# How to sync PDF bookmarks from MacOS Preview to iOS Apple Books?

Tags: ios, pdf, preview, books

Apple Books on MacOS opens PDF files in Preview. Preview can bookmark texts using CMD-D. When I open the same book with Apple Books on iOS the bookmarks are not transferred over. I have cloud sync to enabled and the books are automatically made available in iOS books.

How do I keep my bookmarks in sync on MacOS and iOS?

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting in Books.app Preferences to sync Bookmarks across devices, or not. Make sure that's on.

[image]

Comment: It was checked.

Comment: The problem is that Books on MacOS opens the PDF files in preview and not with the Books app. The books therefore have no sync data. According to https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8640512 it is not possible to open PDFs in Books. One solution I am considering is convert the PDF to ePub and use the sync feature in Books, another is to drop books use only a PDF reader.