# Is there an API to Apple Books sync metadata?

Tags: icloud, books

Apple Books can sync books over iCloud. Is there an API I can use to access metadata on my books, such as title and bookmark locations. 
This question is a follow up to the unanswerable, [How to sync PDF bookmarks from MacOS Preview to iOS Apple Books?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/374797/how-to-sync-pdf-bookmarks-from-macos-preview-to-ios-apple-books).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no publicly available API for that.